# Performance mySQL: Long string in one column in database table or add extra columns?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, database-performance

if I have a muli-dimensional array like that I take from a form submit:

```
$participants = array(

    'participant1'=> array(
        'name'=>'jim',
        'age' => '15',
        'grade' => '8th'),

    'participant2'=> array(
        'name'=>'tom',
        'age' => '17',
        'grade' => '9th'),
....
);
```

Is it better two store whole array into one db column named "Participants" or create a separate column in the row for each participant **PERFORMANCE** wise if i have a maximum number of participants?

Comment: It's hard to answer a question about performance if you don't know what the usage of the table will actually be.  What kinds of queries do you expect to be run against this data?  Will it be mostly inserts?  updates?  selects?  What part of the data is going to be needed to be updated / selected most frequently?  If you don't have a good guess it's better to just write a normalized table structure since any kind of denormalization for performance would be premature.

Comment: I will only need to fetch by row at this point, but I think I will normalize the data in the way specified by @NullPointer. Thank you for your help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using separate column would be better at the point of normalization also if you need only name or age than it would be better you dont need to fetch all